# Bootstrap 4 cards responsive with same height on multiple rows

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm new to design and Bootstrap so bear with me.

I want to have a number of cards with equal height and width (not fixed but responsive) on all rows, or put in another way, all cards should be as tall and wide as the biggest of them all . Any solution is welcome, not limited to Bootstrap.
In example below on large screens the row and card height is increasingly bigger and on medium screens almost every row has different height:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: All cards have the same height. Do you want the anchor tags  to be aligned at the bottom?

Comment: Can I get the CSS too? Or just embed the code here.

Comment: please share what you have tried.

Comment: the cards are not the same height, the one with one paragraph is shorter than the one with 3 paragraphs.
CSS is only  basic Bootstrap <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">, no custom CSS file.
Same as scripts, only basics:
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS-->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
I have tried:
class="row align-items-center"
class="row row-eq-height"

Comment: I have also tried:
class="card-deck" (this is a whole other thing, just failed),
a div with class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch" containing a div with class="card h-100 mb-4" <-- with partial success

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for about two weeks now, and information on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/ is not enough. If anyone knows a more detailed documentation or any other way of reaching the solution please share. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding `style="height: 200px; max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;"` to all the divs with the class of **card-body**

Here's the code:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body" style="height: 200px; max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body" style="height: 200px; max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body" style="height: 200px; max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body" style="height: 200px; max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body" style="height: 200px; max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body" style="height: 200px; max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body" style="height: 200px; max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body" style="height: 200px; max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 my-3 d-flex">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x440/4472c4/FFFFFF" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body" style="height: 200px; max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This will make all the rows of the same height.

Comment: Thank you Zoha. My images are not all the exact same size/height and this changes the card format, also the scrolling mechanism needs to go but I can set images to fixed values and find a height that won't trigger the scroll. It does help me a lot. Much appreciated!